# Passing values from HTML page to Batch file

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file, plink

I have a batch script which logs into a linux machine and executes few commands and shows output (using plink). I want this script to be run in different linux machines, so the difference is just in the IP/username/password (either one, or two or all) in the program. I have given a onclick target to these batch files from HTML. So, just one click will target batch file, login to machine, execute the command and One button executing one script.

Now here is the trouble. There are more than 100 linux machines which require these scripts and its tedious to just change the script and upload it in every server. Also, i want these scripts to run on a single click.

I prefer saving the ip/username/password in one single batch file.
For example:

1=10.1.1.1 and uname pwd
2=10.1.1.2 and uname pwd

I wish HTML file to send the value either as 1 or 2 to the batch file and it executes the program accordingly.

If there is any other way to do also, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to run a script on 100 linux machines?

Why are you using HTML?

Use ssh and scp (or rsh and rcp)

you can send script file to remote machine.

you can execute the script on the remote machine.

you can batch those remote jobs too.

Comment: Hi, i am using HTML just to be user friendly. HTML page has the links to these scripts. These scripts login and execute commands in the remote linux machine. Also, the working of the script is same. The difference lies in the ip/username/password in that script.

Comment: How do you invoke a script file from HTML? can I see part of your code? If you can invoke a script, you might be able to pass arguments too. Why don't you use parameters for ip/username/password.

Comment: Hi, i use window.open to invoke the script. Separate clicks for separate scripts. Let me know how to pass value to invoke a particular hardcoded IP in that script. which will avoid writing N different scrpits for N machines